# sweetjs adding : ''

Tags: javascript, node.js, sweet.js

I am trying to write a macro with sweetjs to go from

```
{a,b,c}
```

to

```
{a:'',b:'',c:''}
```

basically I want to list the attributes of an object and create an empty prototype with that attributes.

The rule I have written is

```
macro basic {
  rule { { $x (,) ... } } => {
    {($x = 3)(,) ...}
  }
}
```

and if I have

```
basic { a, b, c }
```

it expands to

> { a = 3, b = 3, c = 3;}

but if I change the `= 3` in `: ''` I got

> Unexpected token : [... ( a : ) , ...]

(Plus I don't know why it add a `;` at the end of the expansion after `c = 3`)

Any idea?

Comment: what happens if you replace "($x = 3)" with "{$x:3}" ?

Comment: Unexpected token , [... } , { b : ...]

Comment: maybe pass : as string ? ($x ":" 3)

Comment: Unexpected string [... ( a : 3 ) , ...] :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have resolved in a different way, since I didn't know how to use the : (since it is a special character used to specify the type of a token) I have used a temp variable:

```
macro basic {
  rule { { $x (,) ... } } => {
    var tmp = {};
    (tmp [toString $x] = undefined)(;)
    ... 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$()` instead of bare parens to make the key-value pairs read as a single repeated pattern.

```
macro basic {
  rule { { $x (,) ... } } => {
    { $($x: 3) (,) ... }
  }
}
```

It's worth noting, though, that this isn't a case where you need a macro. A normal function could do this quite easily — you'd just need to use parens instead of curly braces and strings instead of bare identifiers.

Comment: Still a lot to learn about Javascript. How can I turn {'a','b','c'} to {'a' : 3,'b': 3,'c': 3} with a function? (I notice that {1,2,3} gives back 3 on chrome console, and not an error as I thought,  but what is {1,2,3} supposed to be in javacript?)

Comment: @user1544128: Well, you wouldn't use brackets for delimiters; you'd use parentheses, but otherwise it would look externally the same. You just do something like `function basic() { var out = {}; for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) out[args[i]] = args[i]; return out; }` And then, just like you'd write `basic{'a', 'b', 'c'}` with the macro, you could write `basic('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem, one of the reason why I am using macro, is that I am trying to avoid using string.

Comment: @user1544128: Ah, I see. Yes, then you could need to use the macro version. I'll update the answer to clarify the difference.